# vb.net Read Craigslist Data

Tags: vb.net, craigslist

Hello I was reading a few articles on how to get data from websites reading the websites source code. With that said I created a Routine to get Craigslist Data for computer gigs for New York and Pittsburgh as shown below. For some reason(could be my lack of knowledge in this area) I only receive 25 records each for both Pittsburgh and NewYork. Is it possible to get the whole listing for today or maybe  even a data range

```
Friend Shared Function GetCraigslist() As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("description")
    dt.Columns.Add("Title")
    dt.Columns.Add("link")

    Dim XMLDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    list.Add("https://pittsburgh.craigslist.org/cpg/index.rss")
    list.Add("http://newyork.craigslist.org/cpg/index.rss")

    For Each link In list

        XMLDoc.Load(link)
        Dim nTable As NameTable = XMLDoc.NameTable
        Dim nsManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(nTable)

        nsManager.AddNamespace("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
        nsManager.AddNamespace("item", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/")
        nsManager.AddNamespace("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
        Dim XMLItems As System.Xml.XmlNodeList = XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//rdf:RDF/item:item", nsManager)

        XMLDoc.Save("C:\development\data.xml")
        For Each currentItem As Xml.XmlNode In XMLItems
            Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            R("Title") &= currentItem.SelectSingleNode("item:title", nsManager).InnerText
            R("description") &= currentItem.SelectSingleNode("item:description", nsManager).InnerText
            R("link") &= currentItem.SelectSingleNode("item:link", nsManager).InnerText
            dt.Rows.Add(R)
        Next
    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```